# Como passar um array na função Query do php?

Tags: php

Bom, estou precisando passar dois no query do php, mas não consigo passá-los sem ser da seguinte forma:

```
$coluna = implode( ',' , $colunas);

$date = implode( " ',' " , $dates);

$teste2 = "'$date'";

//O teste2 está gerando algo como: 'exemplo', 'exemplo'

$sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($coluna)

VALUES ($teste2)";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

      echo "<br>Dados enviados com sucesso!";

  }

  else {

    echo '<br>Não foi possível enviar os dados!';

  }
```

Do jeito que está deu certo, mas achei que ficou muita gambiarra fazer dessa forma, acredito que exista alguma forma melhor de fazer!

- $colunas e $dates são os arrays que estão chegando, o tamanho deles é indefinido, já que irei passar esses dados em diversos lugares.
- Coloquei " ',' " como implode

Comment: Eu recomendo que utilize queries parametrizadas ao invés de jogar os valores dessa forma, pois pode estar vulnerável a SQL Injection.

Comment: Acho que [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library) pode te ajudar nesse caso.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o serialize também: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php .Mas utilize o prepare para evitar sql injection

Comment: Isso é Mysqli ou PDO? Porque pode fazer diferença

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar esta função é mais simples.

```
function insertBD($array, $tbName){
        $variavel_insert_colunas = "";
        $variavel_insert_valores = "";
        $count = count($array)-1;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if($i < $count){
                $virgula = ",";
            }else{
                $virgula = "";
            }
            $variavel_insert_colunas .= $key.$virgula." ";
            $variavel_insert_valores .= "'".$value."'".$virgula." ";
            $i++;
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tbName." (".$variavel_insert_colunas.") VALUES (".$variavel_insert_valores.")";

        return $sql;
    }
```

A função utiliza-se assim

```
$array = array('nome' => $_POST["nome"], 'texto' => $_POST["texto"]);
$result = $conn->query(insertBD($array, "comentario"));
```

Na função `insertBD` o 1º parametro é o array com as colunas e com os dados o 2º parâmetro é o nome da tabela.

Comment: Se eu inserir 5 dados, esta função fará com que os 5 sejam inseridos no banco de dados?

Comment: Sim, com essa função pode inserir os dados que quiser.